# mono Newbie. Installed but env vars not set.. maybe things missing

Tags: mono

I'm just installing mono to learn how it all works.

I installed mono (mono-2.10.9-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe) for the first time and just started to follow on through the Mono Basics page to verify the installation.

http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_Basics

I was surprised that the installer didn't set up the **PATH** env variable , but once I'd done that I was able to get the first example compiling/running.

But I'm getting compile errors on the second example. So am wondering if I am missing further environment variables/settings?
Are the environment variables used by mono documented anywhere?

I'm also just wondering if the installer is ok or should I be looking for another one...
The error messages are as follows:

> C:\Users\Vida\Desktop\Learning\Mono>gmcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0
>
> error CS2001: Source file `Files' could not be found
>
> error CS2001: Source file
>   `(x86)/Mono-2.10.9/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/pango-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found
>
> error CS2001: Source file
>   `(x86)/Mono-2.10.9/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/atk-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found
>
> error CS2001: Source file
>   `(x86)/Mono-2.10.9/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gdk-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found
>
> error CS2001: Source file
>   `(x86)/Mono-2.10.9/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/gtk-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found
>
> error CS2001: Source file
>   `(x86)/Mono-2.10.9/lib/mono/gtk-sharp-2.0/glib-sharp.dll' could not
>   be found
>
> Compilation failed: 6 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: why do you test Mono on Windows? It works better in nix platforms (because in Windows you have Microsoft's .NET anyway). If you just test it on Windows you will get the wrong idea about its stability and maturity

Comment: Well... I don't know much about mono but I wanted to use it with Visual Studio on windows and then pass the code to my colleague who is using a  Mac... Don't I have to get it working with mono on Windows first? I thought maybe there was a difference with some libraries etc.. I'm just trying to find out about Mono but I can't even get started..

Comment: Use Mono on Linux/Mac, you'll get a better picture of what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like some component is confused by the spaces in `Program Files (x86)` (which is presumably the installation directory.) Try setting the `PATH` using its short name (normally `Progra~2`) , or reinstall to a directory that doesn't have spaces. You can also try additionally setting the `MONO_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jester. I tried changing the path to have
c:\Progra~2\Mono-2.10.9\bin
in it.. but same errors...

Comment: I notice from looking into the gmcs.bat file that it is expecting an environment variable called %MONO_OPTIONS% to be present.. this does not exist though.. Shouldn't the installer have made this?

Comment: `MONO_OPTIONS` is optional, you can pass extra arguments to mono through that. Shouldn't cause any problems if it's not defined. Did you try installing somewhere else?

Comment: Hi again Jester. YES that worked. I reintstalled in C:\mono and now I have been able to get the second example compiled and working. Thank you very much for your help.